# Is it a good idea to put sudo apt install softwareA in a Docker file?

Tags: docker

When we need use some software such as softwareA to a docker image, we put something like `sudo apt install softwareA`. Does that mean whenever the docker image is created, it will install the softwareA? Since we will create the docker image frequently and the softwareA will be installed again and again? Is that a good practice? What's a better alternative, such as include the executable files of softwareA in docker image directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base image with all software you need installed and use this image in your final dockerfile, in this case you will be installing packets only during the base image build process.